# Getting .NET Exceptions on Asychronous Postbacks

Tags: asp.net, exception, asynchronous, postback

I have a GridView that is inside of an UpdatePanel.  I am using the RowCommand event to insert data, but currently if an exception is thrown, it is not being written to the trace like I want.  Is there a way I can output the exception message when using the asynchronous postback?

Comment: Do you know the exception? It would be more useful if you can tell us more about the exception you're getting. Or is the problem that you don't know which exception you're getting?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem...I don't know what the exception is. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've struggled with something like this before. If, in your ScriptManager tag, you turn off Partial Page Rendering,

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager"  
EnablePartialRendering="false" />
```

you should then see the ASP.NET YSOD which should enable you to diagnose the problem. Turn partial rendering back on once you've fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

During asynchronous postbacks, the exceptions are not sent to the client, instead the ASP.NET ajax mechanism handles the errors. Whenever an unhandled exception occurs on the server side, an `alert` message-box will be shown to the user containing the exception message. To handle it in your own way, you can tap into [PageManager's EndRequest](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/11/30/ASPNETAJAXPageRequestManagerbeginRequestendRequestEventsUpdateProgress.aspx) event like this -

```
Sys.Application.add_init(__AppInit);
var __pageManager;

function __AppInit() {
    __pageManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    __pageManager.add_endRequest(__EndRequest);
}

function __EndRequest(sender, args) {
    var error = args.get_error();

    if (null != error) {
        args.set_errorHandled(false);
    }
}
```

Some more references [here](http://encosia.com/2007/07/18/how-to-improve-aspnet-ajax-error-handling/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397429.aspx).

Comment: First link is dead. Second link gives a malware warning.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your method that is running the async code in a try catch, write the error to trace in the catch.

If it is not hitting the code, then are you handling the right Gridview Event?  For example if you have a button with a delete command, but are handling the code in the GridViewCommand and do not handle the Event GridViewDeleted it would throw an exception.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I've already tried writing the exception to trace, but it's not working.